# Unable to get controller loaded into my angularjs module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to split my angularjs controllers into files but failing everytime.

Directory Structure:

```
--public--
        --js/controller/resturant.js
        --js/master.js
        --index.php
```

Code for master.js

```
angular.module("rsw",['rsw.controller']);
```

Code for resturant.js

```
    angular.module('rsw.controller').controller('resturant', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.data="Test"
}]);
```

Code for index.php

```
--
<div ng-app="rsw">
  <span ng-controller="resturant">
    {{ data }}
  </span>
</div>
--
```

EDIT:
I've included only 'master.js' in my index.php, do I need to import 'resturant.js" too?

Comment: You've created a module 'rsw' and created your controller in another module 'rsw.controller' module. Did you add the 'rsw.controller' module as dependency in 'rsw' module?

Comment: Yes, still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the correct [module definition](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) call. That is, `angular.module(name)` *retrieves* a module and `angular.module(name, [requires])` *creates* one.

```
angular.module('rsw.controller', [])
.controller('resturant', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.data="Test"
}]);
```

After creating your module, you need to then make it a dependency of your app:

```
angular.module("rsw",['rsw.controller']);
```

Fixed code:

```js
angular.module("rsw", ['rsw.controller']);
angular.module('rsw.controller', [])
  .controller('resturant', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.data = "Test"
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="rsw">
  <span ng-controller="resturant">
    {{ data }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri Had a small typo in my answer, forgot the `,` in `'rsw.controller', []`. Was that the cause possibly?

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri I have added a snippet containing your code with only my changes posted above, and it works. If you have an error please share the full error + stack.

Comment: This is a single file code, I want to split my controllers in different files!

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri It will work the exact same way with multiple files. If you have 2 <script> tags one after another it will behave the same way. Your error is not possible to fix because you have not provided the necessary info, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` and files are splitted as per above directory structure

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri Just to make sure, do you have `<script src="js/master.js"></script>` **and** `<script src="js/controller/restaurant.js"></script>` in your html?

Comment: Yes all files are included-> new error `restaurant.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you had set up your controller wrong.
Try typing this instead:

```
angular.module('rsw').controller('resturant', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.data="Test"
 }]);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, another mistype problem, try like this:
 `angular.module('rsw').controller('resturant', function ($scope, $http){
    $scope.data="Test"
 });`

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work...

file structure:

```
--public
  --js
    --controllers
      --resturant.js
    --app.js
    --appRoutes.js
--views
  --index.php

// resturant.js
    angular.module('rswCtrl', []).controller('RswController', [$scope, function($scope) {

}]);

 // appRoutes.js

   angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/index.php',
      controller: 'RswController' 
    });
  }]);

// app.js
angular.module('myApp', ['appRoutes', 'rswCtrl']);
```

and then don't forget to include paths to all these files in your index.php file. Hope I'm not missing something..